# $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k!\sin(k)}{k^k}.$ convergence/divergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k!\sin(k)}{k^k}.$$
I would like to know how to proceed when calculating these limits. I take into account that $-1 \leq \sin (k) \leq 1$, I tried the ratio test from the absolute value, so $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k!\cdot 1}{k^k}$, and it came out equal to $1$. I don't know what else to try for this series.

Comment: Use Stirling's Formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ratio test gives the value $1/e$ for $\lim a_{n+1}/a_n$.

So the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n! \cdot 1}{n^n}$$ is convergent.
Seems you just miscalculated.

So the given series

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k! \cdot \sin(k)}{k^k}.$$ is absolutely convergent.

Comment: Oh, so the problem is only in the recalculation, but the solution is correct, I'll look at it in more detail, thank you.

Comment: Yes, the ratio test works here. So this problem turns out to be simple.

Answer (score 5):

Remark that :
$$\begin{align} \left|\dfrac{k! \sin k}{k^k}\right| &\leq \dfrac{k!}{k^k} \\&= \dfrac{1 \times 2 \times \cdots \times k}{k \times k \times \cdots \times k} \\&= 
\dfrac{1 \times 2}{k \times k} \, \dfrac{3 \times 4 \times \cdots \times k}{k \times k \times \cdots \times k} \\&\leq \dfrac{2}{k^2}\end{align} $$
and the series :
$$\sum \dfrac{2}{k^2}$$
converges.